# Why the regression show different results when I turn a factor variable into a dummy variable?

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data, dummy-variable

Why the regression show different results when I turn a factor variable into a dummy variable?

You can see from codes that when I use factor variable directly in a regression, my dummies become as cut.L, cut.Q, cut.C, cut^4. I do not understand why it happens.

Thank you.

Here are my codes:

```
> d5 <- as.data.frame(diamond5)
> d5$cut.alt <- NA
> d5$cut.alt[d5$cut == "Fair"] <- 5
> d5$cut.alt[d5$cut == "Good"] <- 4
> d5$cut.alt[d5$cut == "Very Good"] <- 3
> d5$cut.alt[d5$cut == "Premium"] <- 2
> d5$cut.alt[d5$cut == "Ideal"] <- 1
> d5$cut.fac <- factor(d5$cut.alt)
> model2.1 <- lm(price ~ carat + cut.fac, data = d5)
> summary(model2.1)

Call:
lm(formula = price ~ carat + cut.fac, data = d5)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-17541   -792    -38    522  12721 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  -2074.5       14.2  -145.8   <2e-16 ***
carat         7871.1       14.0   563.0   <2e-16 ***
cut.fac2      -361.8       16.7   -21.7   <2e-16 ***
cut.fac3      -290.8       17.2   -16.9   <2e-16 ***
cut.fac4      -680.6       24.0   -28.4   <2e-16 ***
cut.fac5     -1800.9       39.3   -45.8   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1510 on 53934 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.856, Adjusted R-squared:  0.856 
F-statistic: 6.44e+04 on 5 and 53934 DF,  p-value: <2e-16

> model2.2 <- lm(price ~ carat + cut, data = d5)
> summary(model2.2)

Call:
lm(formula = price ~ carat + cut, data = d5)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-17541   -792    -38    522  12721 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  -2701.4       15.4 -175.06  < 2e-16 ***
carat         7871.1       14.0  563.04  < 2e-16 ***
cut.L         1239.8       26.1   47.50  < 2e-16 ***
cut.Q         -528.6       23.1  -22.85  < 2e-16 ***
cut.C          367.9       20.2   18.20  < 2e-16 ***
cut^4           74.6       16.2    4.59  4.4e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1510 on 53934 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.856, Adjusted R-squared:  0.856 
F-statistic: 6.44e+04 on 5 and 53934 DF,  p-value: <2e-16
```

Comment: You need to post some data that replicate the problem. However, this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735636/interpretation-of-ordered-and-non-ordered-factors-vs-numerical-predictors-in-m

Comment: `cut` is an ordered factor. You created a factor without order. Check out `options("contrasts")` and read `help("contrasts")`.