# Interpretation of .L, .Q., .C, .4… for logistic regression

Tags: r, ordinal

I've done a good amount of googling and the explanations either don't make any sense or they say just use factors instead of ordinal data. I understand that the ``.L`is linear,`.Q` is quadratic, ... etc. But I don't know how to actually say what it means. So for example let's say

```
Primary.L     7.73502       0.984
Primary.Q     6.81674       0.400
Primary.C     -4.07055      0.450
Primary^4     1.48845       0.600
```

where the first column is the variable, second is the estimate, and the third is the p-value. What would I be saying about the variables as they increase in order? Is this basically saying what model I would use so this would be `7.73502x + 6.81674x^2 - 4.07055x^3` is how the model is? Or would it just include quadratic? All of this is so confusing. If anyone could shine a light into how to interpret these `.L`, `.Q`, `.C`, etc., that would be fantastic.

### example

```
> summary(glm(DEPENDENT ~ Year, data = HAVE, family = "binomial"))

Call:
glm(formula = DEPENDENT ~ Year, family = "binomial", data = HAVE)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-0.3376  -0.2490  -0.2155  -0.1635   3.1802  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error  z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -3.572966   0.028179 -126.798  < 2e-16 ***
Year.L      -2.212443   0.150295  -14.721  < 2e-16 ***
Year.Q      -0.932844   0.162011   -5.758 8.52e-09 ***
Year.C       0.187344   0.156462    1.197   0.2312    
Year^4      -0.595352   0.147113   -4.047 5.19e-05 ***
Year^5      -0.027306   0.135214   -0.202   0.8400    
Year^6      -0.023756   0.120969   -0.196   0.8443    
Year^7       0.079723   0.111786    0.713   0.4757    
Year^8      -0.080749   0.103615   -0.779   0.4358    
Year^9      -0.117472   0.098423   -1.194   0.2327    
Year^10     -0.134956   0.095098   -1.419   0.1559    
Year^11     -0.106700   0.089791   -1.188   0.2347    
Year^12      0.102289   0.088613    1.154   0.2484    
Year^13      0.125736   0.084283    1.492   0.1357    
Year^14     -0.009941   0.084058   -0.118   0.9059    
Year^15     -0.173013   0.088781   -1.949   0.0513 .  
Year^16     -0.146597   0.090398   -1.622   0.1049    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 18687  on 80083  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 18120  on 80067  degrees of freedom
AIC: 18154

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 7
```

Comment: Can you add the code you use to get these results? Or are you just looking for an explanation of how logistic regression works? If so, you might be better off posting on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Posted on stackexchange and it got removed for being "off-topic" for some reason. I don't have code as this was a made up example but what I am trying to do. I have added code and output for my specific problem right now in the post.

Comment: Great, thanks. Can you also paste the data i.e. the output of `dput(HAVE)` so that we can run your code on the data? A reproducible example always helps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735636/interpretation-of-ordered-and-non-ordered-factors-vs-numerical-predictors-in-m

Comment: Perhaps not important since you have lots of data, but you might want to look into additive models for the year effect (`mgcv::gam(... + s(Year) + ...)`), which would fit smooth functions for the effect of Year.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

That output indicates that your predictor `Year` is an "ordered factor" meaning R not only understands observations within that variable to be distinct categories or groups (i.e., a factor) but also that the various categories have a natural order to them where one category is considered larger than another.

In this situation, R's default is to fit a series of polynomial functions or contrasts to the levels of the variable. The first is linear (.L), the second is quadratic (.Q), the third is cubic (.C), the fourth is quartic (Year^4), and so on. R will fit one fewer polynomial functions than the number of available levels. Thus, your output indicates there are 17 distinct years in your data.

You can think of those 17 (counting the intercept) predictors in your output as entirely new variables all based on the categorical order of your original variable because R creates them using special values that make all the new predictors orthogonal (i.e., unrelated, linearly independent, or uncorrelated) to each other. Note that this means one **can no longer substitute original values for year into the model**.

One way to see the values that got used is to use the `model.matrix()` function on your model object.

```
model.matrix(glm(DEPENDENT ~ Year, data = HAVE, family = "binomial"))
```

If you run the above, you will find repeated numbers within each of the new variable columns where the changes in repetition correspond to where your original `Year` predictor switched categories. The specific values themselves hold no real meaning to you because they were chosen/computed by R to make all the contrasts linearly independent of one another.

Therefore, your model as labeled in the R output would be:

logit(p) = -3.57 + -2.21 * Year.L + -0.93 * Year.Q + ... + -0.15 * Year^16

where p is the probability of presence of the characteristic of interest, and the logit transformation is defined as the logged odds where odds = p / (1 - p) and logged odds = ln(odds). Therefore logit(p) = ln(p / (1 - p)).

The interpretation of a particular beta test is then generalized to: Which contrasts contribute significantly to explain any differences between levels in your dependent variable? Because your `Year.L` predictor is significant and negative, this suggests a linear decreasing trend in logit across years, and because your `Year.Q` predictor is significant and negative, this suggests a deacceleration trend is detectable in the pattern of logits across years. Third order polynomials model [jerk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_(physics)), and fourth order polynomials model [jounce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jounce) (a.k.a., snap). However, I would stop interpreting around this order and higher because it quickly becomes nonsensical to practical folk.

Similarly, to interpret a particular beta estimate is a bit nonsensical to me, but it would be that the odds of switching categories in your outcome at a given level of a particular contrast (e.g., quadratic) as compared to the odds of switching categories in your outcome at the given level of that contrast (e.g., quadratic) less one unit is equal to the odds ratio had by exponentiating the beta estimate. For the quadratic contrast in your example, the odds ratio would be `exp(-0.9328)` = 0.3935, but I say it's a bit nonsensical because the units have little practical meaning as they were chosen by R to make the predictors linearly independent from one another. Thus I prefer focusing interpretations on the sign and significance of a given coefficient as opposed to its magnitude in this circumstance.

For further reading, here is a webpage at UCLA's wonderful IDRE that discusses [how to interpret odds ratios in logistic regression](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-how-do-i-interpret-odds-ratios-in-logistic-regression/), and here is a crazy cool but intense cross validated answer that walks through [how R chooses the polynomial contrast weights](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105115/polynomial-contrasts-for-regression).

Comment: thanks @the-mad-statter !  Do you know how to prevent glm() from converting the apparently ordered factors into these polynomial contrasts?  Or do we need to change what might be arbitrary numeric factors to something it won't think is ordered, say by converting them to text?

Comment: OK, I see there is an option to specifically define factors to be `ordered=F` - that does the trick!

Comment: one meager "up vote" does not do you justice. You should run for president

Comment: What is the level of the ordered variable that is not entering regression? The last one? Right? therefore, if k=5, the first four levels will enter the regression, and the last one, it will be out of regression. Therefore, you add all ODDS, and the remaining ODDS represents the last one? How you determine the p value of the level that was not inside of regression?

Comment: @Estatistics, I would suggest asking this as a new question - perhaps on [cross validated](stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @the-mad-statter. Great response but please what values can be possibly fed in to ``` Year.L or year.Q, Year.C etc``` in the equation logit(p) = -3.57 + -2.21 * Year.L + -0.93 * Year.Q + ... + -0.15 * Year^16`? Does  Year^16 for say the year 2000 mean 2000**16?

Comment: @Charles, no, the predictors in the model do not really have a direct relationship to specific years anymore. They are now values chosen by R to represent polynomial trends.

Comment: @the-mad-statter. Thank you very much. This means it is not a typical formula where values can be fitted in to replace `Year.L `, `Year.Q`, `Year.LC` am I right?

Comment: Correct, you cannot just substitute year values directly into the model.

Comment: @the-mad-statter Some of this is clear but when you write the final terms as `...+Year^16` I think you are leaving the naive reader under the impression that the linear predictor would be formed by simply plugging Year to the 16th power. I don't think that is correct. The first few terms are labeled as they would be for a polynomial contrast and I think all the terms are in fact orthogonal contrasts. The model woul be impossibly difficult to interpret and I think the OP should have been instructed on how to use the `contrast` function to restict the complexity of the polynomial model.

Comment: @IRTFM I agree, and will further emphasize that year can no longer just be substituted into the model as this is the second mention of this issue (@Charles also asked). But I will leave specification of the model using the `Year^x` terms as such because that is how R labels the coefficients above cubic.