# Interpreting Estimate of categorical variable coefficient in lm() summary() in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm, categorical-data

I have a linear model of class "lm" that I am viewing with summary(lm), a toy version of which is:

```
fit <- lm(Strength ~ Age + Sex, data = mydata)

summary(fit)
```

Understandably, `Age` is a continuous variable while `Sex` is a categorical variable. The relevant part of the `summary(fit)` output looks like:

```
             Estimate 
(Intercept)  -1.838e-01
Age          -5.264e-03
Sex.L        3.260e-01
```

How should I interpret this, specifically the categorical variable? I understand this to mean:

*Strength = -0.1838 + (0.005264 * Age) + (0.326 * Sex)*

but is this correct, and what value would `Sex` take? 1 for one sex, and 0 for the other? And how should I check which sex takes the value 1? Since my factor levels for Sex are Male and Female, I assume .L is a dummy variable for one of them, but I don't know how to check this.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

The name for the coefficient is "Sex.L"! This implies that `Sex` is an ordered categorical variable, and polynomial contrast encoding instead of treatment encoding was used. In this case, *Sex* in your equation does not simply take 0 or 1.

---

You really need to convert this ordered factor to the usual factor first:

```
mydata$Sex <- factor(mydata$Sex, ordered = FALSE)
```

You can check `levels(mydata$Sex)` at this stage. The 1st level will be dropped, and the coefficient of `Sex` is for the 2nd level. Note that using a different contrast will result in different coefficients.

---

You can also control levels to be in your desired order, say:

```
mydata$Sex <- factor(mydata$Sex, levels = c("Male", "Female"), ordered = FALSE)
```

Note that changing the order of levels gives different regression coefficients, too.

---

Anyway, as long as `Sex` is the usual factor (i.e., `is.ordered(mydata$Sex)` is FALSE), treatment contrast encoding will be applied. The 1st level is coded as 0, while the 2nd level is coded as 1. Suppose the fitted model coefficients are `a`, `b` and `c`, then the equation will be:

```
Strength = a + b * Age + c * Sex
```

where `Sex` is 0 for the 1st level, and 1 for the 2nd level.

---

**A bit of background:**

The "L" in "Sex.L" means "Linear", which is an indication of polynomial contrast. If the factor has 4 levels instead, we will see "L" (Linear), "Q" (Quadratic) and "C" (Cubic).

However, if `Sex` is the usual factor, the reported name should be "SexMale" or "SexFemale". Yes, this is informative enough.

- If we see "SexMale", then "Female" is the 1st level, so in the equation, *Sex* is 0 for Female and 1 for Male.
- If we see "SexFemale", then "Male" is the 1st level, so in the equation, *Sex* is 0 for Male and 1 for Female.

This naming convention for categorical variables after contrast encoding is very helpful.

---

**A reproducible example**

Since OP did not provide a reproducible example, I decided to simulate a dataset (where `Sex` is an ordered factor) to help readers follow what I said above.

```
mydata <- structure(list(Strength = c(-0.4484, -0.4584, -0.4765, -0.4676, 
-0.4979, -0.507, -0.5094, -0.5071, -0.5046, -0.5346, -0.5302, 
-0.5298, -0.5354, -0.5489, -0.5646, -0.5858, -0.5731, -0.5368, 
-0.5418, -0.5521, -0.5967, -0.5826, -0.5751, -0.5914, -0.6069, 
-0.5831, -0.6045, -0.6111, -0.618, -0.6375, -0.634, -0.6212, 
-0.6496, -0.6387, -0.6387, -0.6695, -0.6413, -0.6499, -0.6763, 
-0.6826, -0.6579, -0.7051, -0.6982, -0.7004, -0.7101, -0.6964, 
-0.6958, -0.7583, -0.7247, -0.7117, -0.7328, -0.0037, -0.003, 
-0.0095, 0.0137, -0.0228, -0.025, -0.0339, -0.041, -0.0271, -0.0303, 
-0.0633, -0.0572, -0.0542, -0.0648, -0.087, -0.0983, -0.0625, 
-0.0832, -0.0776, -0.1046, -0.1158, -0.1331, -0.1137, -0.1288, 
-0.1366, -0.1538, -0.1346, -0.1348, -0.1698, -0.1726, -0.1798, 
-0.1888, -0.1735, -0.1724, -0.183, -0.2001, -0.2029, -0.1812, 
-0.2126, -0.2086, -0.2278, -0.2279, -0.2294, -0.208, -0.2575, 
-0.258, -0.2356, -0.2417, -0.2406, -0.2683, -0.2914), Age = c(10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 
50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 
38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 
51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L), Sex = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Female", "Male"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor"))), row.names = c(NA, -102L), class = "data.frame")
```

A model that OP got:

```
fit1 <- lm(Strength ~ Age + Sex, data = mydata)
#(Intercept)          Age        Sex.L  
#  -0.178985    -0.005426     0.329874  

is.ordered(mydata$Sex)
#[1] TRUE
```

Convert `Sex` to the usual factor:

```
mydata$Sex <- factor(mydata$Sex, ordered = FALSE)

is.ordered(mydata$Sex)
#[1] FALSE

levels(mydata$Sex)
#[1] "Female" "Male"  

fit2 <- lm(Strength ~ Age + Sex, data = mydata)
#(Intercept)          Age      SexMale  
#  -0.412241    -0.005426     0.466512
```

Control order of levels:

```
mydata$Sex <- factor(mydata$Sex, levels = c("Male", "Female"), ordered = FALSE)

is.ordered(mydata$Sex)
#[1] FALSE

levels(mydata$Sex)
#[1] "Male"   "Female"

fit3 <- lm(Strength ~ Age + Sex, data = mydata)
#(Intercept)          Age    SexFemale  
#   0.054270    -0.005426    -0.466512
```

---

**Extensive reading**

- [Interpretation of ordered and non-ordered factors, vs. numerical predictors in model summary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25735636/4891738)
- [Interpretation of .L, .Q., .C, .4… for logistic regression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57297771/4891738)

(I was made aware of these Q & A just now.)

Comment: Dear Zheyuan Li, thank you for this helpful response. Yes, I was thrown by seeing Sex.L rather than seeing something like "SexMale" and was not sure how to interpret it. This makes sense and I will change the factors as you suggest. Hopefully this detailed answer will also prove useful to others in the future. Thank you again.

Comment: After trying mydata$Sex <- factor(mydata$Sex), levels(mydata$Sex) prints "[1] "Female" "Male" " and is.ordered(mydata$Sex) gives "[1] TRUE".

I tried mydata$Sex <- factor(mydata$Sex, ordered = F), which changes the output of is.ordered(mydata$Sex) to "[1] False". However, the summary(fit) still shows "sex.L" rather than, e.g., "SexMale".

Any thoughts?

Comment: N.B. there are no indications of the other levels described by Zheyuan Li, i.e., there are not "Sex.Q" or Sex.C" coefficient rows. I am not sure whether this is relevant or not.

Comment: @PhelsumaFL I wrote: **If the factor has 4 levels instead**, we will see "L" (Linear), "Q" (Quadratic) and "C" (Cubic).

Comment: @PhelsumaFL You need to refit your model after updating `Sex` in your data. Again, had you provided a reproducible example, you would not have been delayed in getting a working solution. Learn this lesson and accept the answer.

Comment: I don't take orders from you. Learn some manners.