# interaction terms (.L, Q, C, ^4, and ^5) and main effect in clogit()R

Tags: r

I'm running a univariate logistic regression analysis:.

```
> modEpi <- with(imp30, clogit(Prognosis ~ Epidermal_contour, strata(Set_ID)))
```

I get the interaction terms (.L, .Q, .C, .^4, and .^5). However, I want to get the main effect of the predictor="Epidermal_contour" and not the interaction terms. Does anyone know how to get that?

```
> summaryPoolEpi=summary(pool(modEpi), conf.int = TRUE, exponentiate = TRUE)## e
> summaryPoolEpi
                 term estimate std.error   statistic       df    p.value     2.5 %    97.5 %
1 Epidermal_contour.L 0.782666 0.2491813 -0.98341729 210.9379 0.32652872 0.4789046 1.2790984
2 Epidermal_contour.Q 1.425971 0.2361749  1.50250164 210.2856 0.13446781 0.8951888 2.2714695
3 Epidermal_contour.C 0.530852 0.2571401 -2.46275099 209.1418 0.01459575 0.3197580 0.8813034
4 Epidermal_contour^4 1.298370 0.2581982  1.01127713 210.1770 0.31304659 0.7804535 2.1599822
5 Epidermal_contour^5 1.022575 0.2352206  0.09490628 211.2418 0.92447924 0.6431634 1.6258069
```

Comment: `Epidermal_contour` is an ordered factor -- is this intended? (ps there doesn't seem to be  interaction terms as oyu only have one predictor)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, indeed it is an ordered factor. However, why don't I get an overall effect of the predictor Epidermal_contour? Additionally, in the Epidermal_contour, the categories have different variables and not Epidermal_contour.L, Epidermal_contour.Q...)

Comment: Regarding the output, a search term would be "polynomial contrasts" which is the default for ordered factors.  I'm not quite sure what you mean by an " overall effect " in the summary of a categorical predictor -- are you wanting to run an `anova` (im not sure of clogit has an anova method)

Answer (score 2):

As @user20650 points out in comments, `clogit` has an `anova()` method that you can use to test the overall effect of an input variable that expands into multiple predictor variables (orthogonal polynomial, factor, spline, etc.). You need to create the *nested* model (i.e., a model that drops the term you're interested in testing) and compare it, e.g.:

```r
library(survival)
cc <- clogit(case ~ tocc + tocc:education + strata(id), logan2)
## create nested model: drop the interaction between tocc & education
##  in order to test that term's effect
cc2 <- update(cc, . ~ . - tocc:education)
anova(cc, cc2)
Analysis of Deviance Table
 Cox model: response is  Surv(rep(1, 4190L), case)
 Model 1: ~ tocc + tocc:education + strata(id)
 Model 2: ~ tocc + strata(id)
   loglik  Chisq Df Pr(>|Chi|)    
1 -1016.0                         
2 -1178.6 325.33  4  < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

In your case the nested model would include only an intercept (`Prognosis ~ 1`).
I'm not sure how this interacts with `mice::pool()` though.

For the meaning of `L`/`Q`/`C`/etc. terms, see [Interpretation of .L, .Q., .C, .4… for logistic regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57297771/interpretation-of-l-q-c-4-for-logistic-regression)