# labelling of ordered factor variable

Tags: r, statistics, gtsummary

I am trying to produce a univariate output table using the  `gtsummary` package.

```
structure(list(id = 1:10, age = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("c", "b", "a"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), sex = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), country = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("eng", "scot", 
"wale"), class = "factor"), edu = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("x", "y", "z"), class = "factor"), 
lungfunction = c(45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 
62L, 45L), ivdays = c(15L, 26L, 36L, 34L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 
9L, 15L), no2 = c(40L, 70L, 50L, 60L, 30L, 25L, 80L, 89L, 
10L, 40L), pm25 = c(15L, 20L, 36L, 48L, 25L, 36L, 28L, 15L, 
25L, 15L)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

...
library(gtsummary)
publication_dummytable1_sum %>% 
select(sex,age,lungfunction,ivdays) %>% 
tbl_uvregression(
method =lm,
y = lungfunction,
pvalue_fun = ~style_pvalue(.x, digits = 3)
) %>% 
add_global_p() %>%  # add global p-value 
bold_p() %>%        # bold p-values under a given threshold
bold_labels()
...
```

When I run this code I get the output below. The issue is the labeling of the ordered factor variable (`age`). R chooses its own labeling for the ordered factor variable. Is it possible to tell R not to choose its own labeling for ordered factor variables?

[image]

I want output like the following:

[image]

Comment: if either of the answers below solved your problem you are encouraged to click on the check-mark to accept one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like many other people, I think you might be misunderstanding the meaning of an "ordered" factor in R. *All* factors in R are ordered, in a sense; the estimates etc. are typically printed, plotted, etc. in the *order of the `levels` vector*. Specifying that a factor is of type `ordered` has two major effects:

- it allows you to evaluate inequalities on the levels of the factor (e.g. you can `filter(age > "b")`)
- the contrasts are set by default to *orthogonal polynomial contrasts*, which is where the `L` (linear) and `Q` (quadratic) labels come from: see e.g. [this CrossValidated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735636/interpretation-of-ordered-and-non-ordered-factors-vs-numerical-predictors-in-m) for more details.

If you want this variable treated in the same way a regular factor (so that the estimates are made for differences of groups from the baseline level, i.e. *treatment contrasts*), you can:

- convert back to an unordered factor (e.g. `factor(age, ordered=FALSE)`)
- specify that you want to use treatment contrasts in your model (in base R you would specify `contrasts  = list(age = "contr.treatment")`)
- set `options(contrasts = c(unordered = "contr.treatment", ordered = "contr.treatment"))` (the default for `ordered` is "contr.poly")

If you have an unordered ("regular") factor and the *levels are not in the order you want*, you can reset the level order by specifying the levels explicitly, e.g.

```r
mutate(across(age, factor, 
   levels = c("0-10 years", "11-20 years", "21-30 years", "30-40 years")))
```

R sets the factors in alphabetical order by default, which is sometimes not what you want (but I can't think of a case where the order would be 'random' ...)

Comment: @ Ben, many thanks for your prompt reply and answer, actually i have age as factor variable which has 4 levels (0 -10 years, 11 -20 years,21-30 and 30-40 years). when i run any summary table or regression then r produce the output for these categories (age group) in random order. so i ordered the levels of age variable. but now in gt summary output i get r own labelling for these categories.

Comment: See the update to my answer. I very much doubt "random order" ... ?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to remove the odd labelling for the ordered variables, is to remove the ordered class from these factor variables. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.4.2'

publication_dummytable1_sum <- 
  structure(list(id = 1:10, age = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
                                              2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("c", "b", "a"), class = c("ordered", 
                                                                                                        "factor")), sex = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                      1L, 2L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), country = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                              1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("eng", "scot", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "wale"), class = "factor"), edu = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("x", "y", "z"), class = "factor"), 
                 lungfunction = c(45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 
                                  62L, 45L), ivdays = c(15L, 26L, 36L, 34L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 
                                                        9L, 15L), no2 = c(40L, 70L, 50L, 60L, 30L, 25L, 80L, 89L, 
                                                                          10L, 40L), pm25 = c(15L, 20L, 36L, 48L, 25L, 36L, 28L, 15L, 
                                                                                              25L, 15L)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame") |>
  as_tibble()

# R labels the order factors like this in lm()
lm(lungfunction ~ age, publication_dummytable1_sum)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = lungfunction ~ age, data = publication_dummytable1_sum)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)        age.L        age.Q  
#>       51.17       -10.37       -15.11


tbl <-
  publication_dummytable1_sum %>% 
  # remove ordered class
  mutate(across(where(is.ordered), ~factor(., ordered = FALSE))) %>%
  select(sex,age,lungfunction,ivdays) %>% 
  tbl_uvregression(
    method =lm,
    y = lungfunction,
    pvalue_fun = ~style_pvalue(.x, digits = 3)
  )
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: @ Daniel, many thanks for your prompt reply and answer,  actually i have age as factor variable which has  4 levels (0 -10 years, 11 -20 years,21-30 and 30-40 years). when i run any summary table or regression then r produce the output for these categories (age group) in random order.  so i ordered the levels of age variable. but now in gt summary output i get r own labelling for these categories.

Comment: See Ben's very helpful answer....you don't need ordered factors. The categories are not in a random order, and you can set the order without making the class an ordered factor.

Comment: @ ben and @Daniel. many thanks thats really helpful. have a great evening ahead.